# Dental Work not authorized

Tags: united-states

Contacted dental office to set up fillings for two teeth. Office said there were three together and it was easier to do all three at once. Patient stated that insurance only covered two per year and could not afford to pay out of pocket for the third filling. Stated already had medical bills and would not be able to do the third filling and would do the new calendar year. Dentist did all three fillings and has billed patient for the third filling. Are they responsible for the bill? They were not told three were being done and patient did not state at the time she only wanted two done. Figured the office new she only wanted two done when setting up the appointment.

Comment: Are they willing to split the invoice?

Comment: @MichaelHall I don't think it matters unless they lie about the date the work was done on the next year's invoice. Unless you mean let the 2nd bill wait until OP has the money to pay it.

Comment: I am **fairly** sure that you asked this question a week or such ago...

Comment: @mkennedy, I wasn't suggesting that anybody lie about anything.  People break up payments all the time.  Unless the plan is *very specific* about recording and submitting for approval the dates the actual work was performed there shouldn't be a reason why the dental office couldn't just split the bill.  (i.e. does "cover" two per year mean *pay* for two per year, or you can only have *work done* on two per year?  Those are distinctly different things, so read the plan!)

Comment: Doing medical procedures against a person's wishes opens themselves up to massive litigation in any locale that puts any emphasis on bodily autonomy.

Comment: I did some minor corrective surgery recently that comprised a rather surprisingly amount of paperwork. I asked the nurse if all this was necessary and she said yes if they do a surgery and you can prove they did it without permission I could sue them for enough to bankrupt the hospital.

Answer (score 5):

The patient is responsible for whatever work they agree to, regardless of insurance coverage. The basic legal question is whether the patient knew of and agreed to the treatment, specifically three fillings rather than two. Various patient-staff interactions could be treated differently in court, for example if the patient clearly said that they only wanted two fillings done and nobody said "We're going to do three fillings" after that, then there is no evidence of an agreement to three fillings. On the other hand, a patient being non-responsive to a dentist saying "We're going to take care of those three fillings" followed by patient silence could easily be construed as an agreement. An agreement can be by words, but also by action, or inaction (i.e. going along with the dentist's proposal).

You may be able to work out some deal with the dentist, but if not, they might sic the bill collectors on you, then you would contest the bill. This then gets you into the complex world of how to legally contest debt collection, so working it out with the dentist is clearly the better alternative.